# I got two columns: the focal firm's cusip and participants' cusips

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

My database looks like this:

```
Firm    Agreement id    Year    Cusip_focal        participants_cusips
Abbott Lab  3947    1990        002824            002824 60851C -
Abbott Lab  4441    1990        002824            002824 090597 -
Abbott Lab  5215    1990        002824            002824 47088J -
Mylan Lab   3997    1990        628530            097516 628530 -
Mylan Lab   20967   1993        628530            31528X 628530 -
```

I wanna wipe out focal's cusip from participants_cusips and get new colum for the second firm:

```
partner
60851C
090597
47088J
097516
31528X
```

Could you please help me to solve this issue?

Best regards, Farid

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please show us some code of what you have tried so far. This makes it easier to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Replace()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) function to remove `Cusip_focal` substring from the `participants_cusips` string. Then, remove any leading/trailing spaces using [`Trim()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim) function:

```
SELECT 
  TRIM(REPLACE(participants_cusips, Cusip_focal, '')) AS partner
FROM your_table
```

Comment: Thank Madhur for your answer, it worked very well. How can add this column to the existing table?

Comment: @FaridMammadaliyev use `alter table` to add the column. and then use this query as `update`